# Makecell: Declare default alignment in \usepackage[]

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, alignment, makecell

I want to load the `makecell` package with a default option to make all `\makecell` cells left-aligned by default. What should I substitute in for `OPTIONS` below to make left-alignment the default behavior for `\makecell` cells?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[OPTIONS]{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \makecell{Label \\ 1} & 1234 \\
  \makecell{Label \\ 2} & 5678
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I'm almost certain I've seen this done before, but after playing around with it a bit I can't figure it out, nor can I find it in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf).

Comment: The package `makecell` doesn't offer options, however you can globally set some features of its macro with  `\renewcommand`, for example used font in `\thead`, position of text in `\makecell` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could see, `makecell` does not offer an option to change the default alignment of `\makecell` but you can use `\renewcommand\cellalign{<alignment here>}` in order to globally change the default alignment to your liking.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{cl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \makecell{Label \\ 1} & 1234 \\
  \makecell{Label \\ 2} & 5678
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the manual of makecell you can use t/b/c or r/l/c/p in the options

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tabu, booktabs}
\usepackage[]{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \makecell[l]{Label \\ 1} & 1234 \\
  \makecell[tl]{Label \\ 2} & 5678\\
   \makecell[br]{Label \\ 3} & ABCDE
\end{tabular}
    

        \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {lXX}
            \toprule
            Head Col 1 & Head Col 2 & Head Col 3 \\
            \hline
            Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[l]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell} \\
            \addlinespace
            Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[tl]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell} \\
            \addlinespace
            Data Col 1 & Data Col 2 & \makecell[br]{here is \\ my text \\ in the cell} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I should have clarified I already knew about this. I was hoping for a way to declare a global default alignment with something like ```\usepackage[align=left]{makecell}``` (which doesn't work).